# Connect Netgear JGS524E switch to Asus RT AC88U router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I want to connect a switch to a Asus RT AC88U router, but have some problems.
When I connect the switch to a port in the router, the network, internet and Wifi is disconnected.

When disconnect the switch it turns to be normal working.
I am not that familiar with networks and switches, so my question is of anybody can help me out with the correct settings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any change regarding the status LEDs on the AC88U when it stops working? // One of the devices may have an electrical fault.

Comment: Reset the Switch to Factory Default.  "Insert a straightened paper clip or a similar device into the hole of the Factory Default button and hold for two to three seconds".   Make sure the Port on the Router works (connect a laptop to it). Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Netgear has an ip-address configured (probably 192.168.1.1) that conflicts with the ip-address of your router (Asus touters uses by default 192.168.1.1 as well).
Tell-tale sign of this is that your computers still have connection (link-leds are on) but there is no communication possible.

Reset the Netgear to factory defaults. Then it should pick up an IP-adress from the DHCP service on the router, which removes the conflict.

This is a managed switch. If you just want to use it as a dumb switch without using its managed features the reset to factory defaults is highly recommended anyway. In case of these Netgear switches the factory default makes it revert to the "dumb switch" configuration.

Something so obvious (to me at least) that I forgot it to include in the original answer:
Make sure to connect the switch on a LAN port of the router. Don't put it between router and the ISP entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

The IP adres of the switch is another, but the gateway is 192.168.1.1
I assume that's the problem, because it's the same as on the router?

Can I set the IP to static and change the gateway to 192.168.1.2 maybe?

Comment: @Dick Don't touch the gateway setting on the switch. That is supposed to point to the router. (In fact all your devices have it set to the router. The router even tells them to do that!) Leave the switch on DHCP (that is the easiest and guaranteed to be correct in your setup).  And make sure to connect the switch on a LAN port of the router. Don't put it between router and ISP entrypoint.,